# SQL Server, using or statement condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using a query which its searching inside a table for two conditions. I will give an example:

```
Select * 
from Customers 
where mobile= '" + textboxt1.Text + "' or Phone = '" + textboxt1.Text + "'
```

The query returns me the first row which mobile or phone numbers is equal with my `textbox1.Text`.

I need to set a condition: start looking "entire table" for find the first 'or' statement(mobile). If there is not exist any result then go and  search again entire table using the second or condition (Phone).

Is there any easy way which i can write my query? Or do I need to use a case for this?

Comment: Please please please parametrise your SQL! Stop injected values! Also, you really need to name your objects. `textboxt1` and`textboxt2` is going to be meaningless to anyone (including you) when you review your application in more than a week's time. [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: On a different note, SQL Server 2008 is now completely unsupported. You should really be looking at upgrade paths as soon as possible.

Comment: I'd suggest something like `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (Select 'a' as Bob, * from Customers where mobile= @Value UNION ALL Select 'b' as Bob, * from Customers where phone = @Value) ORDER BY Bob`. This will give you the mobile matches earlier than the phone matches.

Comment: @Shmeeku: The question is tagged with C#, so this code makes far more sense in that language than it does in T-SQL.

Comment: "Unsupported" doesn't convey the full weight of things. Sql Server 2008 is now **end of life**. That means no new updates are issued at all... _not even critical security patches_. Understanding this helps make it clearer why it is _dangerous and irresponsible_ to continue using this older version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that not more than one record in the table would match on `mobile`, and that not more than one record would match on the `phone` (which seems relevant given your description of your use case), you could use `top 1` and conditional ordering:

```
select top 1 * 
from Customers 
where mobile= @textboxt1 or phone = @textboxt2
order by case when mobile= @textboxt1 then 0 else 1 end
```

If a record matches on `mobile`, the conditional ordering clause will put it in first position, and `top 1` will eliminate the (possible) other record matching on `phone`. Else, the (only) matching record on `phone` will be retained.

Note: don't trust user input. Use [prepared statement and query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection) at all times. I modified the query so it uses parameters (`@textboxt1`, `@textboxt2`).

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes improve performance by choosing a `UNION` instead of an `OR`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
    SELECT *, 0 Ordinal
    FROM Customers
    WHERE mobile = @number

    UNION ALL

    SELECT *, 1 Ordinal
    FROM Customers
    WHERE phone = @number  
) t
ORDER BY Ordinal
```